# Значение "скрытность" и "неискренность"

Tags: семантика

Вот захотелось понять, как, не залезая очень глубоко в толковый словарь, определить разницу между этими понятиями.

Контекст такой. Мне тут между делом рассказала одна знакомая:
*"Я сказала про Имярекова, что он человек неискренний. А мне возражают, что он он просто скрытный по характеру".* И мы оба задумались, а в чем разница. И вообще может такое быть, чтобы скрытный человек был искренним? Нужны не формальные цитаты, а какое-то такое понимание, на основании которого можно продолжить приведенный реконструированный диалог.

Comment: Ой, да. Спасибо.

Comment: А у вас привилегий не хватает править? Уж заголовок-то - без вопросов, буду только рад. Да и вообще, когда заведомая опечатка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что подразумевать под словом, оттенков значения и  у одного, и у другого хватает.Скрытный - Избегающий откровенности, не рассказывающий другим о себе.Он может не рассказывать о себе, потому что

1.он вообще молчалив по характеру, ни о чём говорить не любит, но доброжелателен;

2.он скрытен - т.е. обычно не делится рассказами о себе, о чем-то внутреннем и важном для себя. При этом может быть общителен, о другом разговаривает охотно. В одной обстановке человек скрытен, а в другой - нет, открыт, вопрос в собеседниках - кому из них человек доверяет, а кому нет; чаще всего скрытный оказывается в некотором отдалении от общества;

3.человек замкнут - это не только слова, это вообще поведение, склонность к одиночеству, к отсутствию контакта с окружающими.

Видимо, я тоже бываю скрытной(не люблю обсуждать свои дела ни с кем,кроме  близких людей,которым я доверяю), но если меня назовут неискренней, я не соглашусь и обижусь.

Искренний - исконное значение "ближний", т.е. близкий человек, готовый открыть душу; но теперь есть и другие значения:чистосердечный, бесхитростный,  прямой, прямодушный. Когда мы называем человека искренним, мы имеем в виду, что он правдиво и открыто выражает то, что думает и чувствует.

Антоним к нему - Неискренний - фальшивый, лживый, притворный,   двуличный, лицемерный,  скрывающий подлинные мысли и подлинные чувства.

Открытый человек, "душа нараспашку" - всегда искренний,выскажет всё, что на душе - и о себе, и о других.

А вот скрытность, по-моему, не всегда связана с неискренностью, наоборот -
человек не хочет лгать, но и не хочет до конца "раскрыться",чтобы не навредить (себе или собеседнику)

Скрытный человек может вполне искренне сказать о Ваши недостатках, о том, что он думает по поводу происшедшего, но умолчать о своих проблемах, чтобы не вешать их на собеседника: "сам справлюсь". Это же скрытность и в то же время искренность?

Comment: Да вот хоть что-нибудь под этим и понять. ))) Скрытный - это о своих проблемах, конечно. Никак не о моих. И не только о проблемах. Хорошо, давайте так. Я вот представил человека, который уже несколько лет в коллективе (ну пусть в виртуальном), но о нем никто ничего не знает. Возникает ощущение, что он что-то скрывает. Может такой человек быть искренним? Как-то не очень стыкуется.

Comment: Может скрывать, а может и не скрывать, а просто не навязываться.Может, его никто и не спрашивал о чём-то, его лично касающемся? Он в сети отвечает искренне, как сам думает, но на вопросы научные, касающиеся психологии вообще, не затрагивая своих переживаний. Здесь так и бывает чаще всего. А есть другие, при ответе на  вопросы везде всовывают: "А вот у меня было..." Это простой, "душа нараспашку", но опять-таки мы не знаем, искренен он, правдив ли или приукрасил себя и рекламирует.А вот неискренен точно лжив.

Comment: -Вы какой-то скрытный... - Да нет, мне скрывать нечего, болтать попусту не люблю, зато искренне Вам рад. Такого мы назовём искренним? Он же сказал искренне о своих чувствах?

Answer (score 2):

Тут вопрос мотивации. Скрытный человек, скрывает что-либо сам по себе, не ища выгоду, одобрение или что-либо ещё. Неискренний же сознательно умалчивает какие-либо факты для личной выгоды. Скрытный человек впоне может при этом почти никогда никого не обманывать, но мотивы его поступков для нас не вседа ясны. У человека же неискреннего мотивы-то как раз известны, но всегда стоит опасаться подводных камней.

Answer (score 1):

*Скрытность* - необщительность, отсутствие склонности раскрывать свои мысли в кругу повседневного общения, рассказывать о своих интересах и образе жизни.

*Неискренность* - склонность к лицемерию из стремления создавать о себе выгодное впечатление, уклончивость в ответах на вопросы, которые могут такое впечатление поколебать; расчётливое стремление скрывать свои истинные эмоции.
Иногда такое качество для придания ему позитивной окраски (в защиту кого-нибудь) дипломатично именуют "политичностью".

**P.S.** Оба этих качества для человека обычно нежелательны. Если говорящий в защиту кого-то противопоставляет скрытность неискренности, значит, он считает первое качество терпимым - на фоне известных собеседникам достоинств этого человека. Такая позиция субъетивна, и в другой ситуации скрытность может оказаться "хуже". Например, следователю по делу об ограблении "скрытность" подозреваемого (со слов близко знающих его свидетелей) может говорить в пользу его способности по-тихому спланировать ограбление банка, в то время как его "неискренность" в общении (со слов тех же людей) о такой способности ему не говорила бы.

Comment: и что? Вот интересно, сколько раз надо написать, что формулировки из толкового словаря меня не интересуют. Своими словами, так чтобы в диалоге можно было воспользоваться.

Comment: Даже не думал в толковые словари заглядывать и не знаю, что в них по этому поводу пишут! P. S. И гуглом не набирал.

Answer (score 1):

С мальства ты какой-то скрытный, Андрюшка. Сроду матери ничего не скажешь, сроду не пожалишься… (М. А. Шолохов).

Неискренность считается отрицательным свойством, неискренний – это все равно что лживый, нам  же нравятся люди открытые, искренние, бесхитростные, светлые, добрые.

Скрытный характер – тоже не лучшее качество, так как в скрытном человеке также можно подозревать фальшь, лживость, неискренность. Но в то же время сочетания личностных свойств возможны разные: скрытный и одновременно гордый, или самолюбивый, или  недоверчивый,  или осторожный и хитрый, а может быть, просто застенчивый, необщительный.

Поэтому скрытность характера человека еще не определяет содержание  его характера.  Например, можно сказать:  у него хорошее сердце, он только скрытный.  Но быть скрытным и одновременно  искренним невозможно.

Comment: Умалчивать о личных переживаниях (быть скрытным) и обманывать (не быть искренним) это разные вещи. Андрей Болконский и романа Л. Н. Толстого был довольно искренним человеком, но неискренности в его поступках и словах мы не увидим. Анатоль Курагин же из того же произведения вполне себе человек открытый, но вот как раз искренности мы в нём не найдём.

Comment: *Но быть скрытным и одновременно искренним невозможно.* - Тогда придется признать, что скрытность частный случай неискренности. Впрочем, вы меня совсем не убедили в том, что "невозможно быть одновременно"

Comment: Вера, а что вы понимаете ''под открытое сердце"? Лично я - искренность.

Comment: Давайте обратимся к грамматике и орфографии: неискренний  (лживый)  и не искренний (не является искренним).  Болконский и Курагин – скрытные люди,  но у Болконского  характер  закрытый, не искренний, а  Курагин – неискренний, лживый человек.

Человек может быть скрытным, но при этом не быть лжецом, то есть вроде бы не следует априори считать его неискренним (лживым). Но о том, что он хороший человек, знают только близкие к нему люди, а остальные видят замкнутость и закрытость, а подозревают  гордость, хитрость, недоверчивость.

Comment: Такой человек может проявлять «частную искренность» в отношениях с избранными, но искренним человеком его назвать нельзя. 
Да, у искреннего человек открытое сердце. Искренний – это идущий от сердца, откровенный, чистосердечный. Может быть, у нас не очень много искренних людей и мы забыли, как они выглядят.  Вообще говоря, слово «искренний» чаще используется для  частных характеристик предметов, поступков, чем для людей: искренний смех,  фильм, интерес.

Comment: Вот цитаты  (каких людей называют искренними): Он же знаете какой, он все рассказывает. Он очень искренний. Он такой человек вообще…Я люблю его, потому что он простой и искренний. И вот еще интересно: «Барственный, чванливый, искренний Фамусов очень правдиво недоумевал, что же это происходит вокруг».